# gridview does not display data based on different queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

```js
this is the geidview code 
 < asp: GridView ID = "GridView1"
 runat = "server"
 AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
 DataKeyNames = "studentID,startDate"
 DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1"
 Width = "1230px"
 BackColor = "White"
 BorderColor = "#CCCCCC"
 BorderStyle = "None"
 BorderWidth = "1px"
 CellPadding = "4"
 ForeColor = "Black"
 OnRowCommand = "GridView1_RowCommand"
 OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound"
 OnPreRender = "gridView_PreRender" >
   < Columns >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "firstName"
 HeaderText = "First Name"
 SortExpression = "firstName" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "lastName"
 HeaderText = "Last Name"
 SortExpression = "lastName" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "studentID"
 HeaderText = "Student ID"
 ReadOnly = "True"
 SortExpression = "studentID" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "startDate"
 HeaderText = "Start Date"
 SortExpression = "startDate"
 dataformatstring = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "endDate"
 HeaderText = "End Date"
 SortExpression = "endDate"
 dataformatstring = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "trainingPlace"
 HeaderText = "Training Place"
 SortExpression = "trainingPlace" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "absenceDays"
 HeaderText = "Absence Days"
 SortExpression = "absenceDays" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "evaluation"
 HeaderText = "Evaluation"
 SortExpression = "evaluation" / >
   < asp: BoundField DataField = "comment"
 HeaderText = "Comment"
 SortExpression = "comment" / >
   < asp: ButtonField ButtonType = "Image"
 CommandName = "redirect_edit"
 HeaderText = "Edit"
 ImageUrl = "~/images/table_Edit.png"
 Text = "Edit"
 ShowHeader = "True" / >
   < asp: ButtonField ButtonType = "Image"
 CommandName = "redirect_delete"
 HeaderText = "Delete"
 ImageUrl = "~/images/table_delete.png"
 Text = "Delete" / >
   < asp: ButtonField ButtonType = "Image"
 CommandName = "sendEmail"
 HeaderText = "Certificate"
 ImageUrl = "~/images/table_certificate.png"
 Text = "Certificate"
 ItemStyle - HorizontalAlign = "Center" / >

   < /Columns>
                   <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" / >
   < HeaderStyle BackColor = "#4DA3B0"
 Font - Bold = "True"
 ForeColor = "White" / >
   < PagerStyle BackColor = "White"
 ForeColor = "Black"
 HorizontalAlign = "Right" / >
   < SelectedRowStyle BackColor = "#CC3333"
 Font - Bold = "True"
 ForeColor = "White" / >
   < SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor = "#F7F7F7" / >
   < SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor = "#4B4B4B" / >
   < SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor = "#E5E5E5" / >
   < SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor = "#242121" / >
   < /asp:GridView>
               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=WESAM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CAMSIS;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"></asp: SqlDataSource >
   < /td>
```

i'm writing a code where the grid view changes based on the selected student id or the chosen item from a dropdownlist. Having said that, my code doesn't work properly. I have tried everything but with no luck. It seems that the gridview displays the first query that is in the page load and ignores everything else.
below is my code. your help is highly appreciated :)

```js
  SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=CAMSIS;Integrated Security=True");
  string grade; //This variable is used to distinct the failed students among the passed ones & to hide the certificate button
  int department_selected;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    idTextBox.Text = "";
    DepDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) //To display the user's profile information once the page loaded
    {
      myCon.Open();

      SqlDataAdapter daTa = new SqlDataAdapter(" select depName from Department", myCon);
      // To copy the department names into an array
      DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
      daTa.Fill(dt1);
      // Foreach loop to terate through the department names array and add the names to the department dropdown list
      foreach(DataRow row in dt1.Rows) {

        DepDropDownList.Items.Add(row["depName"].ToString());
      }

      SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT Intern.firstName, Intern.lastName, Rotation.studentID, Rotation.startDate, Rotation.endDate, Rotation.trainingPlace, Rotation.absenceDays, Rotation.evaluation, Rotation.comment FROM Intern INNER JOIN Rotation ON Intern.studentID = Rotation.studentID";
      myCon.Close();
    }
  }



  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myCon.Open();
    if (DepDropDownList.SelectedIndex == 0 && idTextBox.Text == "") {
      SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT Intern.firstName, Intern.lastName, Rotation.studentID, Rotation.startDate, Rotation.endDate, Rotation.trainingPlace, Rotation.absenceDays, Rotation.evaluation, Rotation.comment FROM Intern INNER JOIN Rotation ON Intern.studentID = Rotation.studentID inner join department on intern.depNumber=Department.depNumber";
      Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('1');window.location='deanInternshipSchedule.aspx';</script>");

    } else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idTextBox.Text)) {
      //            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT Intern.firstName, Intern.lastName, Rotation.studentID, Rotation.startDate, Rotation.endDate, Rotation.trainingPlace, Rotation.absenceDays, Rotation.evaluation, Rotation.comment FROM Intern INNER JOIN Rotation ON Intern.studentID = Rotation.studentID inner join department on intern.depNumber=Department.depNumber where Intern.studentID=" + idTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim() + "";
      Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('2');window.location='deanInternshipSchedule.aspx';</script>");

    } else if ((DepDropDownList.SelectedIndex != 0) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idTextBox.Text))) {
      Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('3');window.location='deanInternshipSchedule.aspx';</script>");

      //SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT Intern.firstName, Intern.lastName, Rotation.studentID, Rotation.startDate, Rotation.endDate, Rotation.trainingPlace, Rotation.absenceDays, Rotation.evaluation, Rotation.comment FROM Intern INNER JOIN Rotation ON Intern.studentID = Rotation.studentID inner join department on intern.depNumber=Department.depNumber WHERE Department.depName='" + DepDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
    }
    myCon.Close();

  }
```

Comment: Where are you binding your gridview ? Where is gridview code ?

Comment: @Coder of Code I have added the gridview code as you see above. there is an sqldatasource which binds the data automatically.

Comment: @CoderofCode please see above